# Insert several chars instead of one into string

Tags: java

I have a string with expression. For example the string is "a + b". I need insert float variables instead of that characters. "a" = 2.4494 and "b" = 5.545466. I convert variables to string and then make from strings with expression and with values char arrays.

```
expr = expressions.get(i)[0]; // string with expression
        for (int j = 0; j < valsListArray.length; j++) {//find characters and values
                                                        //they should have      
            String selection = (String) valsListArray[j].getSelectedItem(); //get 
                                                               //chosen character
            Float valueFloat = segmentAreas.get(j);          //get value
            String valueString = "" + valueFloat;
            char[] charexpr = expr.toCharArray();                           //
            char[] valueChar = valueString.toCharArray();
            char[] ch = selection.toCharArray();
            for (int jj = 0; jj < charexpr.length; jj++) {
                if (charexpr[jj] == ch[0]) {  
                    charexpr[jj] = valueChar[0];    //here is the problem
                }
            }
            String s =new String(charexpr);
            expr = s;
```

but I cant understand how insert the whole charArray instead one character...

Answer (score 3):

For inserting several chars in an array at once, consider using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead. Here's how you'd use it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("initial string");
sb.append("another string");
sb.append(new char[] {'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 's'});
sb.append(1.0f);
String str = sb.toString();
```

Comment: but I cant catch how to find place in the string for the value?

Comment: That depends on what you need to do (I mean: only you know how to find the right insertion point), but `StringBuilder` allows you to insert a sequence of characters in a given position using the `insert()` method

Answer (score 2):

A string is immutable. therefore it is bad practice to try to mutate it.

use [StrigBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object to manipulate strings, it has an insert() method that enables you to do just what you were asking.